# How to get my profile link to work in contact?

Tags: discussion, status-completed

I will like to delete this profile, however to do so I have to post "Your profile link" but no matter what I copy past it won't accept my profile like?

What am I supposed to do?

Comment: Have deleted  your account - will take up to 24 hours.

Comment: @MikeW: good job fixing the issue right away, but maybe you could elaborate a little on what link to send exactly in an answer to make this a useful meta/help question?

Answer (score 2):

in the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/contact) you can choose "I need to delete my user profile" and it should paste in the profile link for you if you're logged in. For example: https://stackoverflow.com/users/12345/username.

If you haven't posted Q&As you can delete from your profile, but this isn't the case with this user, so I've done it with the mod tools.